# How to simulate the formation of chemical bonds by calculating electrodynamic forces?

Tags: electrons, simulations, atoms, chemical-compounds

I had the idea recently that if the interactions between atoms could be calculated, that a large enough computer could simulate biological processes.

What would I need to know to simulate something simple?
For example:

If I had 2 carbon atoms some distance apart, how could I simulate the bonding process and visually represent the carbon atoms exchanging electrons and electromagnetically attracting? Something where I can calculate the new positions of the atom and electron fields each timestep and eventually arrive at a bonded position.

Comment: Molecular dynamics simulation is an active area of current research, and has been for decades. See for example, [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Molecular_dynamics) and [here](http://web.stanford.edu/class/cs279/lectures/lecture4.pdf). Large supercomputers are necessary to model enough atoms to simulate proteins and other interesting biological molecules.

Comment: You're going to need to include quantum mechanics, and you're also going to need to include some mechanism for dissipating energy, or else the carbons will just fly apart again. This strikes me as pretty complicated.

Comment: Yeah. Everywhere I look, the notation and ideas are confusing to understand.I am looking for an easy to understand explanation on what 3d interactions might look like for simple atoms. (Strong force and Electromagnetic force)

Comment: related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/263544/the-exact-mechanism-of-energy-release-durning-bond-formation-on-the-atomic-level

Comment: *(Strong force and Electromagnetic force)* The strong force isn't relevant here.

Comment: @BenCrowell Wouldn't you need to simulate the strong force as well to transfer electrons in a way that simulates real life?